# How can I speed up Dash and Plotly imports?

Tags: python, plotly-dash, plotly-python

For me, the dash and plotly.express packages are taking an excessive amount of time to import. I used this code to check the import times:

```
print("Start")

import time

t0 = time.time()
import dash
print(f"Time to load dash: {time.time()-t0}")

t0 = time.time()
import plotly
print(f"Time to load plotly: {time.time()-t0}")

t0 = time.time()
import plotly.express as px
print(f"Time to load plotly.express: {time.time()-t0}")

t0 = time.time()
from dash import dcc
print(f"Time to load dcc: {time.time()-t0}")

t0 = time.time()
from dash import html
print(f"Time to load html: {time.time()-t0}")

t0 = time.time()
from dash.dependencies import State, Input, Output
print(f"Time for dependencies: {time.time()-t0}")
```

As an output, I got that dash took ~55 seconds, plotly took ~0.6 seconds, plotly.express took ~100 seconds, and everything else took 0 seconds.

I am using a Conda virtual environment for this, with these package versions:

- python: 3.9.10
- dash: 2.2.0
- plotly: 5.6.0

There are some other packages in the venv too, mostly dependents of those packages and pandas.

The virtual environment and the code I want to run are in different directories in the same drive. I used pip and conda channels provided by my workplace to download these packages, if that makes a difference.

What could be causing this?

Comment: `plotly.express` brings in `numpy`, `scipy`, and `pandas`, all of which are huge packages.  Usually, you only pay this penalty once, after which they are in your file cache.  Are you on a very slow processor, or loading from a shared drive?  The first pandas load takes about 7 seconds for me.

Comment: `plotly.express` takes approx 1.3 seconds for me (i am using `vscode` on `windows10` on a several year old laptop. As @TimRoberts says, you only pay this cost once...  maybe try to uninstall and reinstall all related packages...

Comment: @TimRoberts thanks for the insight. The processor is 2.59 GHz, would that be enough? Also, yes, both the code and venv are on a network drive, which is shared to others. I'm using a Citrix Remote Workspace, so if I saved the venv and code on the C: drive, they'd be removed in the weekend reboot that my workplace performs.

Comment: So, copy it all locally, make your changes, and update the network copy.  It's likely the loading from a network driver that's killing you.  And with Citrix, you're sharing the server processor with all the other users.